# service.create() returning "Cannot insert duplicate key" Dynamics crm 2013

Tags: c#, workflow, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to write a plugin for Dynamics CRM 2013, and so far I can't get it to work. I've managed to sort of track down the error. It seems to be crashing when I call service.Create(newAppt) with an error message of ""Cannot insert a duplicate key"", and I can't seem to track down what exactly is going wrong. Below the code is the tracing program's complete output. I've been over the examples on the msdn several times over the last three hours and I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace NoteCopier
{
public class NoteCopier : CodeActivity
{
    //This header is for input parameters. We don't need it.
    [Input("Appointment")] //Parameter name //was Annotation
    [ReferenceTarget("appointment")] //Parameter type, we usually pass in the entity logical name 
    public InArgument<EntityReference> Appointment { get; set; }
    //This is an entity reference^. 

    //A list is a data structure that preserves the order of the elements that are put into it. 
    //A set is a data structure that does not allow duplicate objects. Order is NOT guaranteed in a set.
    //EntityReference returns 3 properties: Logical Name, ID and Name (often, but not always the primary key)

    private object setValueSafely(AttributeCollection collection, string key, object val)
    {
        if (!collection.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            collection.Add(key, val);
        }
        else
        {
            collection[key] = val;
        }

        return val;
    }

    Entity getAppointment(Guid id, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        /*ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet("activityid", "actvitytypecode", "description", "location",     "requiredattendees", "optionalattendees",
            "scheduledstart", "scheduledend", "subject");*/
        Entity r = (Entity)service.Retrieve("appointment", id, 
            new ColumnSet("activitytypecode", "description", "location", "requiredattendees",     "optionalattendees",
            "scheduledstart", "scheduledend", "subject")); //was service.Execute //also grabbed activityid before

        return r;
    }

    IEnumerable<Entity> GetRelatedEntities(IOrganizationService service, string primaryEntity, Guid primaryEntityId, string relationshipName, string targetEntity)
    {
        //the related entity we are going to retrieve
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = targetEntity;
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("objecttypecode", "notetext", "annotationid");

        //the relationship that links the primary to the target
        Relationship relationship = new Relationship(relationshipName);
        relationship.PrimaryEntityRole = EntityRole.Referenced; //important if the relationship is self-referencing

        //the query collection which forms the request
        RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntity = new RelationshipQueryCollection();
        relatedEntity.Add(relationship, query);

        //the request to get the primary entity with the related records
        RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
        request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = relatedEntity;
        request.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("activityid");
        request.Target = new EntityReference(primaryEntity, primaryEntityId);

        RetrieveResponse r = (RetrieveResponse)service.Execute(request); //was service.Execute

        //query the returned collection for the target entity ids
        return r.Entity.RelatedEntities[relationship].Entities;//.Select(e => e.Id);
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        //Activity code
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
        TraceServiceWrapper trace = new TraceServiceWrapper(service, tracingService, "ApptNote");
        EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();
        Relationship relationship = new Relationship("Appointment_Annotation");

        trace.Trace("Plugin Started!");
        trace.Trace("Message Name: ", context.MessageName);
        trace.Trace("Primary Entity Name: ", context.PrimaryEntityName);
        trace.Trace("Primary Entity Id: ", context.PrimaryEntityId);
        trace.Trace("PluginExecutionContext: ", context);
        trace.Trace("Post Context:");

        #region try
        try
        {
            trace.Trace("About to get apptEntity");
            EntityReference apptEntity = new EntityReference();
            trace.Trace("About to set apptEntity");
            apptEntity = Appointment.Get(executionContext);
            trace.Trace("Set apptEntity");

            Entity newAppt = new Entity("appointment");
            Entity oldAppt = getAppointment(apptEntity.Id, service);

            trace.Trace("apptEntity ID: ",apptEntity.Id);
            trace.Trace("newAppt ID: ",newAppt.Id);
            trace.Trace("oldAppt ID: ",oldAppt.Id);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> a in oldAppt.Attributes)
            {
                //continue;
                if (a.Key != "activityid")
                {
                    setValueSafely(newAppt.Attributes, a.Key, a.Value);
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> a in newAppt.Attributes)
            {
                //setValueSafely(newAppt.Attributes, a.Key, a.Value);
                trace.Trace("XYZ-Key: ", a.Key);
                trace.Trace("XYZ-Value: ", a.Value);
            }
            trace.Trace("about to call for new apptID");
            Guid apptID = new Guid();

            try
            {
                apptID = service.Create(newAppt);
                trace.Trace("Grabbed apptID : ", apptID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trace.Trace("Unable to create apptID: ", ex);
                trace.HandleException(ex);
                return;
            }

            List<Entity> results = GetRelatedEntities(service, "appointment", apptEntity.Id, "Appointment_Annotation", "annotation").ToList();
            trace.Trace("Created results: ", results.Count);
            foreach (Entity e in results)
            {
                Entity note = new Entity("annotation");

                trace.Trace("Entity Type: ", e.GetType());
                trace.Trace("Logical Name: ",e.LogicalName );
                trace.Trace("ID: ",e.Id );
                trace.Trace("Starting loop");
                trace.Trace("  ");

                foreach (var a in e.Attributes.ToList())
                {
                    if (a.Key == "annotationid")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    trace.Trace("   Value: ", a.Key);
                    trace.Trace("   Contains: ", a.Value);
                    trace.Trace("   ToStr: ", a.ToString());
                    setValueSafely(note.Attributes, a.Key, a.Value);
                }
                Guid noteID = service.Create(note);

                if (noteID == null)
                {
                    trace.Trace("Service.create(note) failed.");
                    continue;
                }
                //We need to create the relationship between our new Entity and our new notes.
                //relationship.PrimaryEntityRole = EntityRole.Referenced; //important if the relationship is self-referencing
                #region relationship
                trace.Trace("NOTEID1: ", note.Id);
                trace.Trace("NOTEID2: ", noteID);
                relatedEntities.Add(new EntityReference(note.LogicalName, noteID));

                // Create an object that defines the relationship between the contact and account.
                #endregion
                trace.Trace("Ending loop");
            }
            try
            {
                service.Associate(newAppt.LogicalName, apptID, relationship, relatedEntities);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trace.Trace("Crash: ", ex);
            }
            trace.Trace("DOne tracing.");
            trace.HandleSuccess();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trace.HandleException(ex);
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
}



[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Plugin Started!
[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Message Name: : Update

[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Primary Entity Name: : appointment

[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Primary Entity Id: : f6dc676a-8312-e411-93f2-00155d543a19

[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - PluginExecutionContext: :     Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.SynchronousRuntime.SynchronousWorkflowContext

[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Post Context:
[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - About to get apptEntity
[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - About to set apptEntity
[2014-07-23-1933_8037]:7 - Set apptEntity
[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - apptEntity ID: : f6dc676a-8312-e411-93f2-00155d543a19

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - newAppt ID: : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - oldAppt ID: : f6dc676a-8312-e411-93f2-00155d543a19

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : scheduledend

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : 7/23/2014 5:00:00 PM

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : activitytypecode

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : appointment

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : subject

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : Subject 3

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : scheduledstart

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : 7/23/2014 4:30:00 PM

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : organizer

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : requiredattendees

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Key: : optionalattendees

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - XYZ-Value: : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection

[2014-07-23-1933_8087]:12 - about to call for new apptID
[2014-07-23-1933_8387]:42 - Unable to create apptID: :     System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Cannot insert duplicate key.     (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

[2014-07-23-1933_8387]:42 - Cannot insert duplicate key.   at     Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Create(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken,     CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
at NoteCopier.NoteCopier.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
42 - Complete.
```

Comment: I'm getting this same error,

Comment: That would not work for PartyList fields (requiredattendees and optionalattendees in this case). For PartyList fields you will have to recreate those fields using foreach.